# Mining pool found a block after three days but didn't pay me

Tags: mining-pools

[image: screenshot for my mining pool]

The number of blocks found was 327 yesterday and today it is 328, which means that the pool found a block. But when I check my GUI wallet I don't find anything. There are no transactions in my wallet and no balance. Is it a scam or is there another explanation?

The mining pool is xmrfast.com.

Comment: Your effort earned you 0.0006 XMR.  Most pools won't payout until you have a balance of 0.1MXR.  Not a scam, you gotta mine more, a lot more.

Comment: They have a 0.005 min payout.  So you are about 1/8 of the way to a payout.  You might have to set the payout on your dashboard at the pool.

Comment: the interesting thing is to know how the payment really works because at the moment I have not found a real explanation, it is something that I would like to work on for non-technical people, I think it is something what I can focus on

Answer (score 1):

You will not be paid by the pool until you have reached the minimum payout threshold. Furthermore, pools usually only run payouts once a day, so you have to mine till 1) you have reached the minimum threshold and 2) wait for the next payout run.